# Fitting subplots, suptitle, legend into one figure WITHOUT tight_layout

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, gis

I am creating a figure with a title, 16 subplots, and a legend. I cannot for the life of me get it to save nicely. I am going to try my best to explain my predicament but my vocabulary may not be correct, so I apologize in advanced.

If I run my code (end) I receive the following output: [image: Bad Output one]

That is not pretty, everything is overlapping or cut off. If I were to add `plt.savefig()` that is what I get.

I can drag the corners of the pop-up window and that gives me a very nicely spaced figure, and is precisely what I want: [image: Nice Figure]

However, the save function at the bottom of that pop up window does not always work, and I would much rather be able to create a nice figure in my code that i send to the `plt.savefig()` function.

In all my searches I keep seeing `tight_layout` being recommended as a fix to this. The issue with that is it adjusts my plot sizes rather than the spacing between plots, so my titles overlap and my data isn't as visible: [image: booo tight_layout]

I have also tried `constrained_layout()` with zero success

I am really hoping there is an obvious solution I am missing, as taking screen shots of the plot isn't really working for me.

```
eq_csv = r'/here/is/the/file.csv'



import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


eq_df = pd.read_csv(eq_csv)
eq_data = eq_df[['LON', 'LAT', 'DEPTH', 'MAG']] # retrieve only the columns I need
eq_data = eq_data.sort_values(['MAG'], ascending=False)


# Get the NSEW boundaries and the Magnitude min and max
nbound = max(eq_data.LAT) + 0.05
sbound = min(eq_data.LAT) - 0.05
ebound = max(eq_data.LON) + 0.01
wbound = min(eq_data.LON)

xlimit = (wbound, ebound)
ylimit = (sbound, nbound)

magmin = min(eq_data.MAG)
magmax = max(eq_data.MAG)

# Loop through depth slices and create a 4 x 4 figure of subplots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(4,4)
for ax in axes.flat:
    for n in list(range(1, 17)):
        km = eq_data[(eq_data.DEPTH > n - 1) & (eq_data.DEPTH <= n)]
        km = km.sort_values(['MAG'], ascending=True)
        plt.subplot(4, 4, n)  # plot a 4x4 sub plot at the nth location
        scatter = plt.scatter(km["LON"], km['LAT'], s=10, c=km['MAG'], vmin=magmin, vmax=magmax, alpha = 0.5)
        plt.ylim(sbound, nbound)
        plt.xlim(wbound, ebound)
        plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=4)
        plt.yticks(rotation = 90)
        plt.ylabel('Latitude', rotation = 90, size = 6)
        plt.xlabel('Longitude', size = 6)
        plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.65, wspace=0.25)
        plt.gca().set_title('Depth = ' + str(n - 1) + 'km to ' + str(n) + 'km', size=8, fontweight = 'bold')  # set title of subplots
        plt.suptitle('Magnitude of Events at Different Depth Slices, 1950 to Today', size = 20, fontweight = 'bold')

plt.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.8) #adust location of plot
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.15, 0.01, 0.7]) #location of color bar
cbar = fig.colorbar(scatter, cax=cbar_ax)
cbar.set_alpha(1)
cbar.set_label('Magnitude', rotation = 270, labelpad = 10)
cbar.draw_all()
plt.show()
plt.savefig('save/location')
```

Comment: Constrained layout won’t help if your suptitle is too big for the page.  Suggest you make your figure larger using the figsize kwarg of subplots and make the figure bigger to start

Comment: @rebekah So `fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 4, figsize=(20,18))` or something similar via experimentation.

Comment: ```figsize()``` worked after some fiddling! Thank you!